# Spring Security 3.2 Can't Logout

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring Security java configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
               ...
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
   }
```

And according to the document (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/), the logout URL is the same as the previous version as `j_spring_security_logout` (Interesting to know any other URLs in the login form have been changed). The URL doesn't work for me.

Anything missing?

Comment: can u share your SS XML?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in detail.

Comment: Which version of Spring Security (the jar files)?

Comment: @OhadR I use Java configuration as shown in my question.

Comment: @KingMaker My logout code with Thymeleaf: <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a href="/" th:href="@{/j_spring_security_logout}" th:text="#{header.logout}">Logout</a></li>. After clicking the link. The logout link is still shown.

Comment: @holmis83 I stated the SS version on the title of my question and only SS 3.2 comes with Java configuration.

Comment: if u want help, share more info. if u use spring, share your spring' XML...

Comment: Can you point me to where it states that he logout URL is j_spring_security_logout? The URL is a POST to /logout. Additional details can be found in http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html#logging-out

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring 3.2 and Java Config, they have changed the default URLs/field names to prevent info leakage (people being able to work out you are running a spring app by looking at the field names/URLs - it touches upon the change briefly here (although this only mentions the username/password/etc - not explicitly the logout, but I assume it has been changed for the same reasoning): http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity.

If you update your link to post to `/logout` it should work.

If you look at the source (click through the Java code config) of the classes you will see the `logout()` method called from your config is on `HttpSecurity.class` and that applies the class `LogoutConfigurer.class` - you can see here the default matcher that is now being applied :

```
public final class LogoutConfigurer<H extends HttpSecurityBuilder<H>> extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<LogoutConfigurer<H>,H> {
    private List<LogoutHandler> logoutHandlers = new ArrayList<LogoutHandler>();
    private SecurityContextLogoutHandler contextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    private String logoutSuccessUrl = "/login?logout";
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;
    private RequestMatcher logoutRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST");
```

(also worth noting, the POST method - plus, if you have not disabled CSRF protection, then you will need to provide the CSRF field as well - as for any post)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out using POST method instead. I missed the section 6.5.3 for some reason. But in 4.2.4. Logout Handling. It says the followings: "The logout element adds support for logging out by navigating to a particular URL. The default logout URL is /j_spring_security_logout, but you can set it to something else using the logout-url attribute. More information on other available attributes may be found in the namespace appendix." Anyway, I get the problem fixed.

Comment: Yep, I found the documentation lacking in some parts for the 3.2 changes - I was previously hitting my head against a brick wall trying to understand some of it, but in the reading the spring code was the best - the code doesn't lie!

Comment: And using eclipse/sts its easy to click through the configuration to see the source - would recommend reading what the http config methods (like logout()) are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your tips. I just sent a note to Rob Winch, the current lead of SS, to add a migration note in the document.